# PHP MySQLI not inserting variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a database with user input,the problem is that while the query i believe is correct it doesnt create any new database if i try without using a variable but puting a database name myself it works but with a variable it doesnt.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{

      echo "Connected successfuly";
  }

$postResult = $_POST[dbname];
echo $postResult;

$runSql = $con->query("CREATE DATABASE".$postResult."");

?>
```

The solution below fixed my issue.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{

      echo "Connected successfuly";
  }

$postResult = $_POST['dbname'];
echo $postResult;

$safeString = $con->real_escape_string($postResult);

$runSql = $con->query("CREATE DATABASE ".$safeString."");

printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $con->error);
?>
```

Comment: just re write like this $con->query("CREATE DATABASE $postResult " );

Comment: You forgot a white space (blank character) between the `CREATE DATABASE` and the name injected by means of the variable. Because of that the statement `CREATE DATABASEsomename` is invalid sql. It has to be `CREATE DATABASE somename`.

Comment: Also take care to validate / escape _all_ data you get handed over from a client. You cannot trust that data, since you have no control over the client, the data may have been manipulated or crafted specially to trick your server into an sql injection attack. Please read about the advantages of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: Tried that suggestion and nothing changed

Comment: In that case check what name has been specified, actually. If it contains _anything_ except lower case letters you have to escape it (as said above) or better not grant it at all. You can also try to place it in backticks (`\``), but that is considered bad style.

Comment: Just tried it with lower case letters and it worked fine how can i make it work with uppercase letters as well as numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from.

```
$runSql = $con->query("CREATE DATABASE".$postResult."");
```

DATABASE is a registered keyword. Plus, it's always good to put indexes in quotes unless you're actually referring to variable defined using

```
define('var', 'my var');
```

So your final code should look like:

```
$postResult = $_POST['dbname'];
echo $postResult;

$runSql = $con->query("CREATE DATABASE ".$postResult."");
```

Comment: Tried this solution and it didnt help its same as before

Comment: Getting
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4' at line 1

Comment: Ok, where is that 4 comeing from? I suspect in `$_POST['dbname']`. before attempting to query database. use `var_dump("CREATE DATABASE ".$postResult."");` you will be able to see your full query to detect the errors. Post it here--edit the question